# How can I check if mysql is installed on ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I need to check if mysql is installed on a ubuntu server. Is there a way to determine if mySql has been installed ? Thanks.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use tool [dpkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg) for managing packages in Debian operating system.

### Example

`dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql` if it's listed as installed, you got it. Else you need to get it.

Comment: can you tell me that location where it get installed in ubuntu ?

Comment: Ask a separate question and I'll be happy to help

Comment: Not sure this is working in the latest Kubuntu 17.1?. In this screenshot it shows it's not installed (shows 'install', not 'installed'). As a test I tried to install the PHP extension, and it shows it's already installed: https://i.imgur.com/RsczcPc.png

Comment: This answer is plain wrong - perhaps you only have `mysql-client` installed?  Or just `mysql-common`?  Or perhaps even `libqt5sql5-mysql` or `lua-dbi-mysql-dev`?

Answer (score 24):

"mysql" may be found even if mysql and mariadb is uninstalled, but not "mysqld".

Faster than rpm -qa | grep mysqld is:

```
which mysqld
```

Answer (score 17):

Multiple ways of searching for the program.

Type `mysql` in your terminal, see the result.

Search the `/usr/bin`, `/bin` directories for the binary.

Type `apt-cache show mysql` to see if it is installed

`locate mysql`

Comment: The apt-cache cmd doesn't seem to work (or at least not on the latest Kubuntu 17.1): https://i.imgur.com/NFOyPUl.png

Comment: Add an asterisk after "mysql":
apt-cache show mysql*

Comment: Actually, I think it doesn't work, either -- it shows some cached information, but not what is installed

Answer (score 8):

With this command:

```
 dpkg -s mysql-server | grep Status
```

Answer (score 3):

**In an RPM-based Linux, you can check presence of MySQL like this:**

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

**For debian or other dpkg-based systems, check like this:**

```
dpkg -l mysql-server libmysqlclient*dev*
```

Comment: While this may solve the OP's problem, a few words of explanation would make this answer even better for the current and future readers of this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of answers. It should have been a simple command. Just type `mysql --version` on your terminal and hit enter.

Answer (score 2):

```
# mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

Output:

```
Enter password:
Uptime: 4  Threads: 1  Questions: 62  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 51  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 45  Queries per second avg: 15.500
```

It means MySQL serer is running

If server is not running then it will dump error as follows

```
# mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

Output :

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

So Under Debian Linux you can type following command

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql status
```

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `mysql` or `mysql -- version` on terminal.

It will prompt version otherwise `Command Not Found`